# High CPU consumption of Apache in Win2008 R2 cluster

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, failover

I Have 2 Win2008 servers running in a failover cluster, I have also installed Apache 2.2 and assigned it as a generic service for the cluster. The setup is designed to cater (at max) 76 clients.

When we performed a dry run of our servers in the actual environment, we noticed the CPU consumption is staying at almost 100%, with httpd.exe using 90% of the total consumption.

Is there any way we can reduce its CPU consumption? Perhaps configuring Apache itself?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I hate to just post a link, but maybe look at this: http://htaccess.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/control-apache-cpu-memory-and-processes-with-httpd-conf/

It appears that you might be able to manually set the max CPU that Apache in general can use.

Depending on the way Apache was configured, I believed there were options to either use more resources and speed up the websites/etc running or to use less resources but at the cost of speed to the sites.

Here's another link to explain RLimitCPU: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105339/how-to-use-rlimitcpu